# How do I control the content page focus?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a listview data on ItemsPage and when I select an item I can edit it and will update on database. My problem is, when a go back to ItemsPage I want to refresh the list

I already tried to call the method OnAppearing to try to refresh in OnItemSelected under the Navigation like this:

```
namespace TesteMasterDatail.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
    {
        ItemsViewModel viewModel;

        public ItemsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
        }

        async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var item = args.SelectedItem as Item;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(new ItemDetailViewModel(item)));

            OnAppearing();

            ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        async void AddItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new NewItemPage()));
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if (viewModel.Items.Count == 0)
                viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

It didnt work cause the refresh happens before the edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to refresh your list after you add new item or edit item in a new page like:

in `ItemsPage` :

```
 public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ItemsPage> (this, "Refresh", () =>
          {
            // refresh the list when the "Refresh" message is received
          });
    }
```

in `ItemDetailPage` or `NewItemPage`,after edit item or add new item:

```
 MessagingCenter.Send<ItemsPage>(this, "Refresh");
```

Of course you could also pass parameter by **MessagingCenter**

Answer (score 0):

`OnAppearing()` should be called for you when the page is navigated to after `PopAsync` is called - you do not need to manually call it.

However, note that your `LoadItemsCommand` will still not fire in this case, because the VM is already initialized.

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#popping-pages-from-the-navigation-stack)

> When the PopAsync method is invoked, the following events occur:
>
> -The page calling PopAsync has its OnDisappearing override invoked.
>   -The page being returned to has its OnAppearing override invoked.
>   -The PopAsync task returns.